# HTTP GET with VBA and special characters in URL

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, special-characters

I'm trying to communicate with Google Distance API via `VBA` in 64bit Excel 365, but having trouble with special character input in street address data. Other threads having similar issues with other HTTP requests, though with output and I struggle to relate.

```
Sub Check_routes()

Dim objRequest, Json As Object
Dim apiKey, apiURL, myOrigin, myDest As String

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

myOrigin = "Tähetorni+1+Tallinn"
myDest = "Sääse+2+Tallinn"
apiURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=" & myOrigin & "&destinations=" & myDest & "&mode=driving&key=" & apiKey
                                                                                              
objRequest.Open "GET", apiURL, False
objRequest.send

...

Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm getting an error response in JSON back stating `Invalid 'origins' parameter`. The problem is special character `ä` in origin & destination. Replacing this with `a` fixes it, but that's not a reliable solution. Is my problem string not being UTF-8 as Google stipulates?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs

Power Query in Excel environment is also perfectly capable in communicating with Google Distance API and has no problem handling special characters - and is a more convenient tool on top of that, however annoyingly generates duplicate requests which is less than ideal with a paid API such as Google Distance. That's the lone reason for going with VBA here.

Is this a `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object problem which cannot handle my input string as is?

Comment: Apparently you need to properly URL-Encode those characters. I fed your two addresses into a [URL Encoder](https://www.urlencoder.org/) and fed those encoded URL's into the api call.  Resulted in a distance of 3.2 mi or 5.2 km which seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change these two lines in your code:

```
myOrigin = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("Tähetorni 1 Tallinn")
myDest = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("Sääse 2 Tallinn")
```

Your code returns a valid string with those changes (also note I replaced the `+` with `<space>` as the function will take care of encoding that also).

By the way, you need to specify data type for each element in a declaration string.  They will **NOT** take the data type of the last element. Rather they will be of type Variant when not specified.

So change these lines also:

```
Dim objRequest as Object, Json As Object
Dim apiKey as String, apiURL as String, myOrigin as String, myDest As String
```

Comment: Thank you, works brilliantly. Didn't realize there's native formula for that in Excel.

As for declaring variables - it wasn't a typo, I did think it works like that too. Thanks again for pointing that out too.